# Linux driver PCI error detection

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, linux-device-driver, pci, pci-e

In my Linux pcie driver for a certain pcie device, I implemented the pcie error
handler functions (error_detected, slot_reset methods, etc).  I want
to trigger a pci error for me to exercise those handlers and observe
its behavior.  I've read from the pci error recovery kernel
documentation that the 1st step is with error_detected method, called
by the system if it detected any error related to the pci device.  The
good thing is that the system will detect it for the driver,
simplifying things.  But I'm having problems with error detection
itself.

I tried to trigger the error via the PCIe device.  On its FW, I
triggered a reset of its PCIe subsystem.  As a result, the I/O rate
dropped to zero and the driver now can't send to the device.
Something indeed happened in their PCIe connection.  However, I
couldn't see my error_detected method being called, when I was
expecting the kernel will detect the PCI error and call the handler.
Instead, some warning message appeared in the console as follows:

irq 16: nobody cared
handlers:
<...>
<...>
Disabling IRQ # 16

What baffles me more is that the injected PCI error seemed to brought
down that IRQ 16 device as well - which is definitely not the irq # of
my driver/device.  This looks like a destructive event in the bus.  Is this result expected for a PCI errors  Any thoughts on why the kernel did not detect that
PCI error?  Is there anything I could possibly missed during
registration of error handler methods?

If that is so, I'd like to ask for other means of injecting PCI
errors, in order for me to exercise my error handlers.  Thanks!

Comment: Are enabling both error reporting and advanced error recovery driver in my Linux driver NECESSARY to get these above handlers to work as they should?

Comment: How did you register your PCIe error detection code with the kernel?  There is a port driver framework for enabling custom PCIe services.

Comment: How did I register?  I followed the instruction in the kernel documentation pci-error-recovery.txt especially on the struct pci_error_handler, and registered err_detected, slot_reset, and resume callbacks.  That's all.  I checked out the AER documentation but not sure if it is a must with the error_handlers.  Does the port driver have error recovery capability for the driver as well?

Comment: Coincidentally, I've also been working on a PCIe port service driver, except for link retraining.  When the module is inserted it calls pcie_port_service_register(), which will pass a pointer to a struct that will advertise itself as servicing a particular PCIe service type and provide callbacks.  The driver loaded for the PCIe bus will call my driver's probe() callback for each type of device on the bus that supports link retraining.  You should check the devices on your system's bus to see if any of them support AER.  I use 'lspci -vv | grep BwNot' to find this capability.